# Call the dialog "Contact the Developer" from application page

Tags: facebook, dialog, modal-dialog, report, contacts

How can I call the dialog "Contact the Developer" from application FAQs ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not something you can call yourself, since it isn't part of the JS SDK.  You will have to build the modal yourself or send the user to the link to fill out a support question.